# PySpark: random number from range (based on a column)

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to generate a column with a random number per each row, but this number has to be in range between of already existing column and -1. If I have:

```
customer existing_value 
   A          -15
   B          -9
   C          -13
```

I would like to receive something like `rand(existing_value, -1)`:

```
customer existing_value random_value
   A          -15            -3
   B          -9             -8
   C          -13            -6
```

I couldn't find a dedicated PySpark solution for this, the sql `rand()` function seems to be too limited. I tried to use the following code, but the function doesn't accept column as an input:

```
random_month.withColumn('random', randint(col('existing_value'), -1))
```

What would be a good solution here? The number of rows is about 100k, so if there is nothing appropriate in PySpark, pandas could be an option if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `randint` function with UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("A", -15), ("B", -9), ("C", -13), ], ["customer", "existing_value"])

df1 = df.withColumn("random_value", F.udf(lambda x: randint(x, -1))("existing_value"))

df1.show()
#+--------+--------------+------------+
#|customer|existing_value|random_value|
#+--------+--------------+------------+
#|       A|           -15|          -5|
#|       B|            -9|          -7|
#|       C|           -13|          -3|
#+--------+--------------+------------+
```

---

Another solution by generating a sequence of numbers from `existing_value` to `-1` then pick randomly one element from the resulting array:

```
df1 = df.withColumn(
    "random_value",
    F.expr("sequence(existing_value, -1, 1)")
).withColumn(
    "random_value",
    F.col("random_value")[F.floor(F.rand() * F.size("random_value"))]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas' apply function for such operations on columns: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html.
One possible solution could be the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame([-15, -20], columns=['existing_value'])
df['random_value'] = df.existing_value.apply(lambda row: random.randint(row,-1))
print(df)
```